# Is a smooth ring a domain?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that smooth and regular is "quasi" the same and that a regular local ring is a domain. Here I start with the definition $A \to B$ is *smooth* if and only if for every square zero extension of $A$-algebras ($M$ is an ideal of $E$ with $M^2 = 0$) 
$$0 \to M \to E \to C \to 0$$
ad for any $A$-lgebra morphism $B \to C$, there is at least one lifting of $B\to C$ to $B \to E$.

I found in the book of Harshorne a proof that the module $\Omega_{B|A}$ of Kähler differentials is a projective module of dimension $\dim(B)$ if $A$ is a ring and $B$ is smooth over it, but I don't know how he gets rid of the hypothesis $B$ is a domain.

So my question is :

> Starting from the definition can we show that $B$ is a domain if it is a local ring, smooth and essentially of finite type over a field ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the rank (and not dimension) of the projective module of Kahler differentials is $\dim B$? It should be the relative dimension.

Comment: If i am over a field it is the same right ? I have edited

Comment: In other words, you are assuming $A$ is a field in your notation, right?